# How to check for a POST method in a ListView in Django views? I'm getting a 405 error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This fails for me. It gives me a "405 Method not allowed error." It is referring to the POST method yes? How does one check for a POST? Or should I do something totally differently?

```
class StuffList(ListView):
    template_name = "list.html"
    queryset = Stuff.objects.all().order_by('-whatever')
    context_object_name = 'stuff'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST:
            q = request.POST.get('q')
            stuff = Stuff.objects.filter(user__icontains=stuff)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'stuff': stuff, 'q': q })
```

In my form, I have the token placed right inside the form action, like so:

```
  <form action="/stuff/" method="post" name="q">
     {% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're making a POST request but you've only defined a GET method. If you add a POST method, it should do the trick :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    stuff = request.POST.get('q')
    stuff = self.get_queryset().filter(user__icontains=stuff)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'stuff': stuff, 'q': q })
```

However, if you're only filtering the list, using the get is a correct solution, in this case, you have to change your form tag `method="post"` to `method="get"` and make you're GET method something like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    stuff = self.get_queryset()
    if request.GET.get('q'):
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        stuff = stuff.filter(user__icontains=q)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'stuff': stuff, 'q': q })
```

Maybe you should look at the Django forms which can do data validation, form generation and much more.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: Can ListViews do Post requests? I keep getting a 405 forbidden error?

Comment: *405 Method Not Allowed* or *403 Forbidden* ? If it's a *403 Forbidden*, I think it's because you're missing the CSRF cookie. In this case, you have to include the `{% csrf_token %}` tag in the form in your template. If you're only filtering the list, maybe you could just override the `get_queryset` method

Comment: I updated my post above. I'm getting a 405 method not allowed. I have the CSRF cookie within the form in my template too.

Comment: If I use the def get approach in your answer, I get this error: Cannot use None as a query value

Comment: I have edited my answer. Sorry, not easy to be error proof without executing the code :)

Comment: awesome thanks. Another question, what if I just want to return the new stuff {'stuff': stuff, 'q': q }) variables to the view without rendering the template?

Comment: You mean to update the list without refreshing the page ? In that case, you have to look to Ajax. But that's more complicated than refreshing the page.

Comment: I mean just update the variables - do I always have to render the page_template?

Comment: Yes, django renders a static page, if you want to refresh the variables without rerendering the template, you have to use Ajax and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Francois (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33876878/1126755) is very helpful. I'd like to add this more generic version of the post handler:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

In this way other aspects of the ListView can remain unchanged.